# How can I insert C code into C++/CLI code?

Tags: c, .net, c++-cli

I have some files written in C that I want to insert into my .NET C++/CLI code.

This C code is huge and has not been written by me, so it would be a hard task to me 'translating' all the code.
How can I insert this code and call the functions I need without any compatibility problems?

I used to think that, if C++/CLI is definitely C++ and C is compatible with C++, there is no problem to insert C code into C++/CLI code. But I've read about something called `extern "C"`, which made me change my mind.

How can I insert the code into my project, preferably in another file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, don't  "insert" or translate anything.  If this C code is not already in a library project like it should be then create one, with a .h file that declares the functions you want to use.  Use extern "C" { #include "foo.h" } in your C++/CLI source file(s).  Link the library in your C++/CLI project.

Comment: i think it's better to do it by headers.

Comment: @HansPassant as simple as that? Great! Thank you!

Comment: @HansPassant is giving me error `error D8045: cannot compile C file 'Device.c' with the /clr option`

Comment: That library project of course should not be a C++/CLI project, given that you want to compile C code.  Only the project that *uses* the C code should use /clr.  Do talk to whomever supported this C code first.

Comment: @HansPassant there is not an option for setting up a different compiler for my `extern "C"` block? I cannot talk to supporter.

Comment: Flagging to close as too broad, because the ideal solution to this problem is well above novice level.

Answer (score 1):

C++ can run C code without modifications. The only difference is the way the names of functions and variables are encoded. The process is called [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Just enclose your C code (headers and source) in a `extern "C"` block:

```
extern "C" {
   ... (C code)
}
```

All C code must be written in such a block. This tells C++ compiler how to treat function and variable names. Read more about `extern "C"` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/).

Comment: What do you mean with 'such a block'? I only can use `extern "C"` one time on my code? Excuse me for my ignorance

Comment: You can use it everytime you are writing C code in C++ programs. Please see [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/)

Comment: Yes, I read it. It resulted to be very helpful to me. Now I'm getting the next error `error D8045: cannot compile C file 'Device.c' with the /clr option`

Answer (score 0):

What Mario is writing is correct. I am just modifying his example below. Just add all the header file declaration like below and compile you code to use all the function declared in c into your C++ application. Also include c libraries into your `make file` as well.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

 //declare your header file here
   #include "your c header file"
  void foo(int i);//your c function

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```