# Is it possible to include C code into a .NET C++/CLI application?

Tags: c, .net, c++-cli

I'm trying to add a C code library into my Visual C++/CLI application (with a UI Form, and compiled using CLR).
I'm using the block `extern "C"{...}`, but it cannot compile because of the next error:

`error D8045: cannot compile C file 'Device.c' with the /clr option`

How can I include this code? Thank you.

(Here in SO exists the next thread: [D8045: cannot compile C file 'serialcommands.c' with the /clr option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880413/d8045-cannot-compile-c-file-serialcommands-c-with-the-clr-option) but it does not seems to be clearly solved...)

Thank you in advance

EDIT: My code is next:

```
// UI main .h class

extern "C"{
#include "Device.h"
}
```

EDIT2: As I said, this is not a duplicate. Not even from question [How can I insert C code into C++/CLI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682152/how-can-i-insert-c-code-into-c-cli-code), which is also mine. In that question I asked about the error D8045 and received a bad reputation due to extending my question. So I've opened this one in order to ask about the error.

Comment: You need to compile that as a native C or C++ library and link it into your C++/CLI project (i.e. the way to include it but not compile it with `/CLR`).

Comment: @crashmstr and how can I make that? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: (Assuming Visual Studio) You need to create a new project in your solution and select Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop -> Dynamic-Link Library (DLL) or Static Library. You should be able to find more information about those online.

Comment: @crashmstr perfect, don't worry. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert C code into C++/CLI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682152/how-can-i-insert-c-code-into-c-cli-code)

Comment: Mixed-mode assemblies are described in the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/mixed-native-and-managed-assemblies)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield it is not a duplicate. In that question I asked how to insert code, and when I notified that I got the error D8045, I suddenly received a bad puntuation because of extending my question. So now I'm asking about the error I couldn't ask on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to right-click the c file. 
Properties->C/C++->General:
 "Common Language RunTime Support" = **No Common Language RunTime Support**

Please be reminded that within the header file include by the c file, there should be no managed code. Often it is easier to keep your brain safe and just make a new project and keep that clean.

Project setting /CLR /No Precompiled Headers

my header used by both

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void func();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

my c code / compiled without CLR

```
#include "Souce.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void func()
{
    printf("test");
}
```

CheckCompileWithC.cpp : main project file.

```
#include "Souce.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Hello World
test
```

Comment: That's right. At the moment I'm trying to insert unmanaged C code into a C++/CLI managed class (which contains the interface). But I need to call the methods of the library from the UI class. It would be possible to achieve this access?

Comment: Should be no problem.

Comment: Isn't that all an duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48682152/9293869)

Comment: but however I'm getting this error...Even if I mark my c file as 'No Common Language Run Time Support'

Comment: The D8045 Error?

Comment: I reedited my answer. I don't get an D8045 Error. @areify You didn't get a the downvote because of the extension but because you did not accepted the answer. Which obviously in the limited setup cannot be longer the D8045 Error

Comment: When you receiving the error D8045 then please go to the properties c++-> Command Line, Choose the Configuration and Platform and check that line. If you copy it to the question, it might enlighten us.